# Bigquery - create a table with repeated integer sequence

Tags: sql, matrix, google-bigquery

I need to find a simple way to turn an integer sequence in Biquery into a matrix with zeros on empty spaces

Example:

```
v1   v2   v3
5    2    1
```

needs to become

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
5  2  1  0  0
0  5  2  1  0
0  0  5  2  1
```

etc.

I looked in all the possible places around but could not find how to do it in BQ or SQL.

Thanks

Comment: add more details with current table strucure and all inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider below solution to be generic enough

```
#standardSQL
WITH sequence AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[5,2,1] AS num
),
numbers AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(num) AS len, 
    ARRAY_CONCAT(num, ARRAY( SELECT 0 FROM sequence, UNNEST(num) AS x)) AS num
  FROM sequence
)
SELECT 
  num[OFFSET(CASE WHEN 1 - n < 0 THEN 2 * len - n ELSE 1 - n END)],
  num[OFFSET(CASE WHEN 2 - n < 0 THEN 2 * len - n ELSE 2 - n END)],
  num[OFFSET(CASE WHEN 3 - n < 0 THEN 2 * len - n ELSE 3 - n END)],
  num[OFFSET(CASE WHEN 4 - n < 0 THEN 2 * len - n ELSE 4 - n END)],
  num[OFFSET(CASE WHEN 5 - n < 0 THEN 2 * len - n ELSE 5 - n END)]
FROM numbers, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, len)) AS n
ORDER BY n
```

You can easily adjust it to any sequence. For this you need to make changes in two places only:

1. adjust ARRAY values in sequence subquery (line 2)
2. add more rows like below into SELECT list

Row:

```
num[OFFSET(CASE WHEN Z - n < 0 THEN 2 * len - n ELSE Z - n END)]
```

you need to add as meny of such so that total number of the row will be `2xZ-1` and each next row has `Z` incremented by 1
This can easily be script - so the whole query (or just SELECT list) will be generated for you then to run

If you are running this in client of your choice (python, go, etc.) - this can be part of your code so the whole stuff is automated

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form:

```
select v1, v2, v3, 0 as v4, 0 as v5
from MyTable
where (...)
union all
select 0, v1, v2, v3, 0
from MyTable
where (...)
union all
select 0,0,v1, v2, v3
from MyTable
where (...)
union all
select 0,0,0,v1, v2
from MyTable
where (...)
union all
select 0,0,0, 0,v1
from MyTable
where (...)
```

Comment: Is there a way to put it in a loop, so that the length would become a parameter? Thanks

Comment: You would want to use UNION ALL instead of UNION

Comment: @Ilja Not as a raw query, maybe as a proc, but I'm no BQ proc expert...